# Dynamic SQL queries for tokio postgres in Rust

Tags: sql, postgresql, rust, tokio-postgres

I am working with tokio postgres for a Rust project where I have a table Home having two columns 'number' and 'address'.
My queries are being sent from the rust source code using the sql client as shown below,

```
let rows = client.query(QUERY, &[&"number", "address"]).await?;
```

where

```
QUERY: &str =
"
SELECT * FROM Home 
WHERE number <= $1 
AND address = $2;
";
```

In the above case, both inputs are valid strings of non-zero length.
Given, this information, I am trying to query the rows of the table following certain rules.
I have provided them below.

1. If the query input 'address' is null, then the AND part of the string will not be there. In the problem only the 'address' parameter can be null only. The 'number' field is always consistently non-empty.
   Some ideas that I came across look like this but the ideas are not that concrete and in the current condition it does not work.
   One example,

   QUERY: &str =
   "
   SELECT * FROM Home
   WHERE number <= $1
   IF $2 IS NOT NULL
   THEN address = $2;
   ";
2. I will have to modify the rhs side SQL queries. I can still create a dynamic string so that at run time the queries will look different according to the case encountered, but the requirement is to handle it directly with the help of a SQL rather than rust.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) function in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Home 
WHERE number <= $1 
AND address = COALESCE($2, address);
```

If *input parameter* `$2` will be null, then the *field* `address` will will be compared against itself, which will always return true (if there are no `null`s in the `address` *field*).

Comment: if the address parameter is null, I will have to unwrap the variable before its inserted into the query method which will throw an error in case. Is there a way to handle this from Rust without me having to implement unwrap().I saw postgres client does not take None

Comment: @bluestacks454, you mean this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73452619/19032206

Comment: yes. This question.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes accross this.  I was able to achieve this by boxing `dyn ToSql + Sync` in a vec and converting it to a slice like `&[&(dyn ToSql + Sync)]` like this

```rust
async fn query<T>(
    client: &Client,
    query_str: &str,
    params: &Vec<Box<(dyn ToSql + Sync)>>,
    from_row: impl Fn(Row) -> T,
) -> Result<Vec<T>, Error> {
    let param_slice = &params.iter().map(|x| x.as_ref()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let rows = client.query(query_str, &param_slice).await?;
    Ok(rows.into_iter().map(from_row).collect())
}
```

You can build queries by populating a Vec of the boxed query conditions.

```rust
fn query_param_pair_from_args(args: Args) -> (String, Vec<Box<(dyn ToSql + Sync)>>) {
    let mut query: String = "".to_string();
    let mut idx = 1;
    let mut params: Vec<Box<(dyn ToSql + Sync)>> = vec![];
    if let Some(x) = args.id_eq {
        let cond = format!("id = ${idx}");
        if query.is_empty() {
            query = cond;
        } else {
            query = format!("{query} and {cond} ");
        }
        idx = idx + 1;
        params.push(Box::new(x));
    }
    if let Some(x) = args.name_eq {
        let cond = format!("name = ${idx}");
        if query.is_empty() {
            query = cond;
        } else {
            query = format!("{query} and {cond} ");
        }
        idx = idx + 1;
        params.push(Box::new(x));
    }
    if let Some(x) = args.name_like {
        let cond = format!("name like ${idx}");
        if query.is_empty() {
            query = cond;
        } else {
            query = format!("{query} and {cond} ");
        }
        idx = idx + 1;
        params.push(Box::new(x));
    }
    if let Some(x) = args.money_in_bank_lt {
        let cond = format!("money_in_bank < ${idx}");
        if query.is_empty() {
            query = cond;
        } else {
            query = format!("{query} and {cond} ");
        }
        idx = idx + 1;
        params.push(Box::new(x));
    }
    if let Some(x) = args.money_in_bank_gt {
        let cond = format!("money_in_bank > ${idx}");
        if query.is_empty() {
            query = cond;
        } else {
            query = format!("{query} and {cond} ");
        }
        params.push(Box::new(x));
    }
    (query, params)
}
```

you can append this to a select all statement with a where.

I have an example here https://github.com/decapo01/tokio-postgres-dynamic-query-example