# Passing None into tokio postgres sql client query method

Tags: postgresql, rust, tokio-postgres

I am using tokio postgres in a Rust project where I have query parameters.

```
 rows = client.query(QUERY,  &[&input1, &input2.unwrap()]).await.expect("error");
```

where QUERY looks like this

```
QUERY: &str = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name=$1 AND Address= COALESCE($2, Address);"
```

`input2` is of type Rust option for which I will have to unwrap input2 before inserting it into the query method. Is there a way to make the query method handle "None" directly.
I can write conditional statements outside but that will make the source code unmanageable for the case where I have multiple optional queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You work with raw queries, tokio_postgres couldn't to manage `None`. In my experience best solution will write your own query builder.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to `.unwrap()` at all and can pass `&input2` as-is. `Option<T>` [implements](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/latest/tokio_postgres/types/trait.ToSql.html#impl-ToSql-for-Option%3CT%3E) `ToSql` where `T: ToSql`, if the value is `None` then it will pass `NULL` to the database:

```rust
let rows = client.query(
    "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name=$1 AND Address=COALESCE($2, Address)",
    &[&input1, &input2],
).await?;
```

Full working code that I tested on my local database is available [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aaa5145ea6e69cef2f4e387648c0f4c3).